# Wrap double-quote images around text

Tags: html, css

I am adding text in a paragraph. I want to wrap quotes around the text (as images).

```
<p class="aboutus" style="font-style: impact;font-size: medium">
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test .
</p>
```

If I want to add double-quotes around the text, this works fine.

```css
p.aboutus:before {
    content: '"';
}

p.aboutus:after {
    content: '"';
}
```

But now if I have the double-quotes in images (`quote1.jpeg` and `quote2.jpeg`), and if I add the `<img src>` in the pseudo selectors, it doesn’t work. Why not?

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the images with the `url()` syntax:

```css
p.aboutus::before {
    content: url('../images/quote1.jpeg'); /* Or wherever it is */
}

p.aboutus::after {
    content: url('../images/quote2.jpeg');
}
```

Note that the URLs are relative to the location of the containing stylesheet; not your page.

Comment: @Kay: There's an issue with how the text wraps in the demo. In some cases, part of the text appears to wrap below the close quote (depending on the browser width). This is due to the very-large line-height of the text, which results from having the large quotes as inline content. To avoid this, the images would have to be short enough to fit within the intended line-height of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you require some very special styling, it may be adequate to use plain text for the quotes, rather than images.

Here's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/HCWDK/3/) with an example of each.

The first one uses plain-text, and the second one uses images. They're virtually identical in appearance (tested in: IE8/9/10, FF, Safari, Chrome, Opera). Both allow quotes of any size to be displayed, without affecting the line-height of the first and last line of text (which occurs when a large image is added inline).

Below is a simplified version of the code (see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/HCWDK/3/) for the full details).

**Plain-text**

```
.text-quotes blockquote {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 0 22px 0;
    text-indent: 36px;
}
.text-quotes blockquote:before,
.text-quotes blockquote:after {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 60px;
}
.text-quotes blockquote:before {
    content: '\201C';   /* Left double quote */
    left: -36px;
    top: 8px;
}
.text-quotes blockquote:after {
    content: '\201D';   /* Right double quote */
    right: 0;
    bottom: -13px;
}
```

**Images**

```
.image-quotes blockquote {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 0 22px 0;
    text-indent: 36px;
}
.image-quotes blockquote:before,
.image-quotes blockquote:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 27px;
    height: 21px; 
}
.image-quotes blockquote:before {
    content: url(http://www.forestpath.org/test/misc/double-quote-left.png);
    left: -35px;
    top: 0;
}
.image-quotes blockquote:after {
    content: url(http://www.forestpath.org/test/misc/double-quote-right.png);
    right: 35px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```